# WheelViewLib's on item click doesn't work on Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-layout

I have WheelviewLib (https://github.com/LukeDeighton/WheelView) used in my project. It works fine on Operating Systems below Marshmallow, But the function on click Wheel Items does not work in Marshmallow.

The below function is never triggered in Marshmallow.

```
wheelView.setOnWheelItemClickListener(new WheelView.OnWheelItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onWheelItemClick(WheelView parent, int position, boolean isSelected) {
                Log.d(TAG,"clicked on  "+position);
                setPopLayout(position + count * 6, v);
            }
        })
```

;

Comment: raise an issue in that library.

Comment: @UMESH0492 what do you mean by that?

Comment: Raise a issue over https://github.com/LukeDeighton/WheelView/issues for right and faster response.

Comment: Thanks @UMESH0492 Hope that helps.